# Why does Bloomberg terminal crop html formatted text?

Tags: html, copy-paste, bloomberg, richtext

I am trying to ease a common workflow of our users by giving them the opportunity to copy information from our app to the clipboard and paste it into Bloomberg chat. Since some of the content is tabular, I use the `text/html` mime type to format it as follows:

```
<div>
  <span>some raw text<span>
  <table>
    <thead>...
    <tbody>...
  </table>
<div>
```

When pasting the resulting clipboard content into Word, Skype, or other rich text enabled targets, it works as expected. However, when pasting to Bloomberg terminal/chat, only the table is pasted while the text above is cropped.

How do I get the whole content to be pasted?

Comment: I am guessing that the problem comes from IB’s own interpretation of special characters / keystroke combinations eg. { and }. The backslash may also have a special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround: since the BB input field seems to parse only tables and ignore the rest of the html document, we added the text as part of the table's header.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">The text I want to appear "before" the table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">(manually break lines to avoid cut-off)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>...
</table>
```

Not great as text might be cropped depending on the number and width of columns and the rendering is not great. Happy to see better ideas :)